# History of fixed point theory

Tags: reference-request, fixed-point-theorems

I am looking for   encyclopedic  references for  fixed point theory and its applications. What is the best reference for this subject?
 thank you.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416899/history-of-the-contraction-mapping-technique.

Comment: Try also [History of Science and Math Stack Exchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

***Fixed-point theorems for compact convex sets*** by
*Mahlon M day* has its introductory remarks regarding the history of Fixed-point theorems.

***A Fixed Point Theorem for Mappings which do not Increase Distances***
by *W. A. Kirk*
(Source: The American Mathematical Monthly)

***A Generalisation of Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem*** by *Shizuo Kakutani*

***Some Properties of Convex Sets
Related to Fixed Point Theorems*** by
*Ky Fan*
(Source: Mathematische Annalen)

Answer (score 1):

- W.A. Kirk, "History and methods of metric fixed point theory", in *Antipodal Points and Fixed Points*, 1995.
- *Handbook of Metric Fixed Point Theory*, edited by Kirk and Sims, 2001.
- *Handbook of Topological Fixed Point Theory*,
  edited by Brown et al., 2005.
- *History of Algebraic and Differential Topology*, by Dieudonné.
- *History of Topology*,  edited by James, 1999.
- S. Park, ["Ninety Years of the Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem"](http://www.math.ac.vn/publications/vjm/vjm_27/toc_27_3.htm), Vietnam Journal 
  of Mathematics Volume 27, Number 3, 1999.