# A strange integral: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {dx \over 1 + \left(x + \tan x\right)^2} = \pi.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

While browsing on [Integral and Series](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/post3169.html), I found a strange integral posted by @[Sangchul Lee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9340/sos440). His post doesn't have a response for more than a month, so I decide to post it here. I hope he doesn't mind because the integral looks very interesting to me. I hope for you too. :-)

[image]

$$\mbox{How does one prove}\quad
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{{\rm d}x \over 1 + \left[\,x + \tan\left(\, x\,\right)\,\right]^{2}} = \pi\quad
{\large ?}
$$

Please don't ask me, I really have no idea how to prove it. I hope users here can find the answer to prove the integral. I'm also interested in knowing any references related to this integral. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cauchy's integral formula may be the way to go.

Comment: @John I guess so, but dunno how to use it

Comment: I guess we have to split the integral 'around' the singularities of $\tan(x)$ which leads to an infinite sum... I'm not sure whether it converges...

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Here is an approach.

We may use the following [result](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html), which goes back to G. Boole (1857) :

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f\left(x-\frac{a_1}{x-\lambda_1}-\cdots-\frac{a_n}{x-\lambda_n}\right)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\: \mathrm{d}x  \tag1
> $$

with $a_i>0, \lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ sufficiently 'regular'.

Observe that, for $x\neq n\pi$, $n=0,\pm1,\pm2,\ldots$, we have $$ \cot x = \lim_{N\to +\infty} \left(\frac1x+\frac1{x+\pi}+\frac1{x-\pi}+\cdots+\frac1{x+N\pi}+\frac1{x-N\pi}\right)$$ leading to (see [Theorem 10.3 p. 14 here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.2445.pdf) and see achille's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015462/a-strange-integral/1016751#1016751) giving a route to prove it)

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f\left(x-\cot x\right)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\: \mathrm{d}x  \tag2
> $$

with $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{1+\left(\small{\dfrac\pi2 -x }\right)^2}$.

On the one hand, from $(2)$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f\left(x-\cot x\right)\mathrm{d}x& =\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\: \mathrm{d}x  \\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+\left(\small{\dfrac\pi2 -x }\right)^2}\: \mathrm{d}x\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\: \mathrm{d}x\\\\
& =\pi \tag3
\end{align}
$$ 
On the other hand, with the change of variable $x \to  \dfrac\pi2 -x$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\!\!\!f\left(x-\cot x\right)\mathrm{d}x & =\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \!\!\!f\left(\dfrac\pi2-x-\tan x\right)\mathrm{d}x \\\\
 &  =\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+\left(x+ \tan x \right)^2} \mathrm{d}x \tag4
\end{align}
$$ 
Combining $(3)$ and $(4)$ gives

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+\left(x+ \tan x \right)^2} \mathrm{d}x=\pi. 
> $$

Comment: This is very clever.  But how does the theorem hold in the limit as $N \to \infty$?

Comment: Jesus, this is brilliant!! +1 But one question (maybe this is stupid question), like Ron G said, how to prove this one $$\cot x = \lim_{N\to +\infty} \left(\frac1x+\cdots+\frac1{x+N\pi}+\frac1{x-N\pi}\right)$$
Do you have any papers that can support that claim?

Comment: @Venus
$$
\cot(x)={\Psi(1 - x/\pi) - \Psi(x/\pi) \over \pi}
={1 \over \pi}\,\left(1 - {2x \over \pi}\right)\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \left(n + 1 - x/\pi\right)\left(n + x/\pi\right)}
$$

Comment: @Venus Thanks. You may just take the logarithmic derivative of $$\displaystyle \sin x = x \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1 - \frac{x^2}{(n\pi)^2} \right)$$ See here: http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.22

Comment: @RonGordon It seems achille has given a route for your legitimate question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Oliver & @FelixMarin, very enlightening :-)

Comment: +1, This is exactly how I proved that identity, motivated by [@orangekids' answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950712/how-to-compute-int-infty-infty-exp-left-fracx2-13x-12611x2-rig/950848#950848). And I am glad that finally a reference is available to me! Thank you!

Comment: This was.so.cool. I'd give this 1k thumbs up, too bad the site can't support it

Comment: The $\cot$ expansion is also attributed to [Mittag-Leffler](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_Expansion_for_Cotangent_Function)

Answer (score 47):

Please view this as an supplement of Olivier's answer.

I will derive a sufficient condition on the meromorphic function involved which
allow one to apply a result similar to that in Olivier's answer.

Let $\phi(z)$ be any meromorphic function over $\mathbb{C}$ which

1. preserve the extended real line $\mathbb{R}^* = \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$ in the sense:
   $$\begin{cases}\phi(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{R}^*\\ \phi^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{R}\end{cases}
   \quad\implies\quad
   P \stackrel{def}{=} \phi^{-1}(\infty) = \big\{\, p \in \mathbb{C} : p \text{ poles of }\phi(z)\,\big\} \subset \mathbb{R}
   $$
2. Split $\mathbb{R} \setminus P$ as a countable union of its connected components $\,\bigcup\limits_{n} ( a_n, b_n )\,$. Each connected component is an open interval $(a_n,b_n)$
   and on such an interval, $\phi(z)$ increases from $-\infty$ at $a_n^{+} $ to $\infty$ 
   at $b_n^{-}$.
3. There exists an ascending chain of Jordan domains $D_1, D_2, \ldots$ that cover $\mathbb{C}$,
   $$\{ 0 \} \subset D_1 \subset D_2 \subset \cdots
   \quad\text{ with }\quad \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty D_k = \mathbb{C}
   $$
   whose boundaries $\partial D_k$ are "well behaved", "diverge" to infinity and $| z - \phi(z)|$ is bounded on the boundaries. More precisely, let
   $$
   \begin{cases}
   R_k &\stackrel{def}{=}& \inf \big\{\, |z| : z \in \partial D_k \,\big\}\\
   L_k &\stackrel{def}{=}& \int_{\partial D_k} |dz| < \infty\\
   M_k &\stackrel{def}{=}& \sup \big\{\, |z - \phi(z)| : z \in \partial D_k \,\big\}
   \end{cases}
   \quad\text{ and }\quad
   \begin{cases}
   \lim\limits_{k\to\infty} R_k = \infty\\
   \lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \frac{L_k}{R_k^2} = 0\\
   M = \sup_k M_k < \infty
   \end{cases}
   $$

> Given such a meromorphic function $\phi(z)$ and any Lebesgue integrable function $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$, we have following identity: $$
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\phi(x)) dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx \tag{*1}
> $$

In order to prove this, we split our integral into a sum over the connected components
of $\mathbb{R} \setminus P$.
$$\int_\mathbb{R} f(\phi(x)) dx
= \int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus P} f(\phi(x)) dx
= \sum_n \int_{a_n}^{b_n} f(\phi(x)) dx
$$ 
For any connected component $( a_n, b_n )$ of $\mathbb{R} \setminus P$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$, consider the roots of the equation $\phi(x) = y$.
Using properties $(1)$ and $(2)$ of $\phi(z)$, we find there is a unique root
for the equation $y = \phi(x)$ over $( a_n, b_n )$. Let we call this root as $r_n(y)$.
Change variable to $y = \phi(x)$, the integral becomes

$$\sum_n \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y) \frac{d r_n(y)}{dy} dy
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y) \left(\sum_n \frac{d r_n(y)}{dy}\right) dy
$$
We can use the obvious fact $\frac{d r_n(y)}{dy} \ge 0$ and dominated convergence theorem to justify the switching of order of summation and integral.

This means to prove $(*1)$, one only need to show
$$\sum_n \frac{d r_n(y)}{dy} \stackrel{?}{=} 1\tag{*2}$$

For any $y \in \mathbb{R}$, let $R(y) = \phi^{-1}(y) \subset \mathbb{R}$ be the collection of roots of the equation $\phi(z) = y$.

Over any Jordan domain $D_k$, we have following expansion

$$\frac{\phi'(z)}{\phi(z) - y} = \sum_{r \in R(y) \cap D_k} \frac{1}{z - r} - \sum_{p \in P \cap D_k} \frac{1}{z - p} + \text{something analytic}$$

This leads to
$$\sum_{r \in R(y)\cap D_k} r - \sum_{ p \in P \cap D_k} p 
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D_k} z \left(\frac{\phi'(z)}{\phi(z) - y}\right) dz$$

As long as $R(y) \cap \partial D_k = \emptyset$, we can differentiate both sides and get

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r_n(y) \in D_k} \frac{dr_n(y)}{dy} 
&= 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D_k} z \left(\frac{\phi'(z)}{(\phi(z) - y)^2}\right) dz
= -\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D_k} z \frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{\phi(z)-y}\right) dz\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D_k}\frac{dz}{\phi(z) - y}
\end{align}
$$
For those $k$ large enough such that $R_k > 2(M+|y|)$, we can expand the integrand in last line as

$$\frac{1}{\phi(z) - y} = \frac{1}{z - (y + z - \phi(z))} 
= \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(y + z - \phi(z))^j}{z^{j+1}}$$
and obtain a bound

$$\left|\left(\sum_{r_n(y) \in D_k} \frac{dr_n(y)}{dy} \right) - 1\right|
\le \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{j=1}^\infty \int_{\partial D_k} \frac{(|y| + |z-\phi(z)|)^j}{|z|^{j+1}} |dz|\\
\le \frac{(M + |y|)L_k}{2\pi R_k^2}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(\frac{M+|y|}{R_k}\right)^j
\le \frac{M + |y|}{\pi}\frac{L_k}{R_k^2}
$$
Since $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \frac{L_k}{R_k^2} = 0$, this leads to

$$\sum_n \frac{dr_n(y)}{dy} = \lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{r_n(y) \in  D_k} \frac{dr_n(y)}{dy} = 1$$

This justifies $(*2)$ and hence $(*1)$ is proved. Notice all the $\frac{dr_n(y)}{dy}$ are positive, there is no issue in rearranging the order of summation in last line.

Back to the original problem of evaluating

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+(x+\tan x)^2} dx$$

One can take $\phi(z)$ as $z + \tan z$ and $f(x)$ as $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.
It is easy to see $\phi(z)$ satisfies:

- Condition $(1)$ - For any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u + iv \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$, we have
  $$\begin{align}
  \Im (\phi(u + iv) - y ) 
  &= v + \Im\tan(u+iv) = v + \Im\frac{\tan u + i\tanh v}{1 - i\tan u\tanh v}\\
  &= v + \tanh v\frac{1 + \tan^2 u}{1 + \tan^2 u\tanh^2 v} \ne 0
  \end{align}$$
- Condition $(2)$ - obvious.
- Condition $(3)$. - Let $D_k$ to be the square
  $$D_k  = \big\{\, u + v i \in \mathbb{C} : |u|, |v| \le k \pi \,\big\}$$
  It is not hard to show $|z - \phi(z)| = |\tan z|$ is bounded above by $\frac{1}{\tanh k\pi}$ on $\partial D_k$.

Combine these, we can apply $(*1)$ and deduce

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+(x+\tan x)^2} dx
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx 
= \pi
$$

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand almost all of your answer, but it looks very cool, so +1. :-)

Comment: as a physicist i really have to get used to this "pure math style" proof, but after doing so i have to say: Really nice work!

Comment: I'm thinking this theorem to solve my homework's problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1017074/146687 Is it possible?

Comment: @Venus, I don't think so. To apply this theorem, the integrand need to have the form of composition of two function $f \circ \phi$. Furthermore, $\phi(x)$ need to looks like $x + $ something...

Comment: Oh no... I'm in trouble now :-(

Answer (score 14):

This integral can also be evaluated by standard contour integration.

Denote $f(z)=i+ \tan z + z$, using the identity:
$$\tan(x+yi) = \frac{\sin(2x)}{\cosh(2y)+\cos(2x)} + \frac{\sinh(2y)}{\cosh(2y)+\cos(2x)}i $$
it can be seen that $f(z) = 0$ has no root in the upper half plane.

Take $R$ to be a large half-integer (to avoid poles of $\tan x$), then $$\tag{1}\int_{-R}^R \frac{1}{f(x)} dx + \int_{C(R)} \frac{1}{f(z)} dz = 0$$
here $C(R)$ is a large semi-circle in upper-half plane with radius $R$. It is a nice exercise to show there exists an absolute constant $C$ such that $|\tan z| < C$ on all $C(R)$, so $$\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{C(R)} \frac{1}{f(z)} dz = \lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{C(R)} \frac{1}{z} dz = \pi i$$

Taking imaginary parts of $(1)$:
$$\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{-R}^R \frac{-1}{1+(x+\tan x)^2} dx +\pi = 0$$

this concludes the proof.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more on why the integrand on the last step approaches to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ ?

Comment: @CLBJ_23  Since the integrand is of $O(1/z^2)$, and the length of $4n$, so $$\left|\int_{S_n} \left( \frac{1}{i-\tan z -z }+\frac{1}{z} \right) dz\right| \leq 4n O(\frac{1}{n^2}) \to 0$$

Comment: First, thanks for taking the time to reply. The part I don't quite get is how from the fact that $\tan z$ is uniformly bounded on $S_n$, we deduce that the LHS is of $O(1/z^2)$ order. Would you mind shed some light here too? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CLBJ_23  $$\frac{1}{i-\tan z -z }+\frac{1}{z} = \frac{i-\tan z}{z(i-\tan z -z)}$$ note the denominator has degree $2$ in $z$, and $\tan z$ is bounded, so it's $O(1/z^2)$.

Comment: All clear now - much appreciated!

Answer (score 13):

The [Inverse Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) gives us
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(g(x))\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sum_{g(x)=\alpha}\frac1{\left|g'(x)\right|}\,f(\alpha)\,\mathrm{d}\alpha\tag{1}
$$
If we integrate along squares, centered at the origin, whose sides are parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes with length $2k\pi$, as $k\to\infty$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{x+\tan(x)=\alpha}\frac1{1+\sec^2(x)}
&=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z+\tan(z)-\alpha}\\[6pt]
&=1\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Letting $g(x)=x+\tan(x)$, $(1)$ and $(2)$ give
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x+\tan(x))\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}
$$
Therefore, applying $(3)$ to $f(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+(x+\tan(x))^2}
&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}\\[6pt]
&=\pi\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on the origin of the 1st line? I cannot figure out how to derive it from inverse function theorem.

Comment: Anyway, this is a very ingenious answer. It is interesting to see what happens when $g(x) = x - \tan x$, my method and your method both fail at some point, perhaps that integral does not admit a simple closed form.

Comment: @pisco125: break the real line into pieces where $g(x)$ is monotonic and apply the inverse function theorem on each piece. Each piece gives a term in the sum where $g(x)=\alpha$.

Comment: @pisco125: Did you have a specific question using $g(x)=x-\tan(x)$? Note that $\frac1{|g'(x)|^2}=\frac1{\tan^2(x)}$. I haven't computed the corresponding sum for the integral, but I think it should be possible.  It won't be $1$ in this case.

Comment: In (1), the corresponding root of $g(x)=\alpha$ has to be real. However, $x-\tan x = \alpha$ in general has two complex roots. When using contour integration to calculate the sum in (2), those complex roots are involved. So the sum in (1) really involves the inverse of $x-\tan x$ to some extend, this complicated the matter. The above problem does not happen for $x+\tan x = \alpha$ because all its root are real.

Comment: I'm a bit confused because what you seem to be describing is a sum of transformed integrals, not an integral over the real line of a sum.

Comment: @RandomVariable: Note that $x+\tan(x)$ runs through the real line once every $\left(\left(k-\frac12\right)\pi,\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi\right)$. We're adding up the contributions for each of those intervals.

Comment: @pisco125: the residues at those two zeros will need to be subtracted, which keeps the sum from being $1$. The sum of all the residues is still $1$, but the sum of the residues on the real line is not.

Comment: @pisco125: yes, the total of all the residues is $1$, but subtracting the two singularities off the real axis gives the sum to be given by the function [$$\sum\limits_{\substack{x-\tan(x)=\alpha\\x\in\mathbb{R}}}\frac{1}{\tan^2(x)}=-1-\sum\limits_{\substack{x-\tan(x)=\alpha\\x\not\in\mathbb{R}}}\frac1{\tan^2(x)}$$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI7gv.png) where the sum on the right is over the two roots not on the real axis.

Comment: If you break up the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f \left(g(x)\right) \mathrm dx$ into a series of integrals and make the substitution $ \alpha=g(x)$ in each integral, how do you end up with an integral over the real axis of a series?  Shouldn't you end up with a series of transformed integrals?

Comment: The left side of $(1)$ integrates $f$ over an infinite sequence of intervals $I_k=\left[\left(k-\frac12\right)\!\pi,\left(k+\frac12\right)\!\pi\right]$ where $g(x)$ ranges monotonically from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. The integral over $I_k$ is $$\int_{I_k}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left.\frac1{\left|g'(x)\right|}\right|_{\substack{g(x)=\alpha\\x\in I_k}}\,f(\alpha)\,\mathrm{d}\alpha$$

Comment: The point of $g=x+\tan(x)$ is that $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\left.\frac1{\left|g'(x)\right|}\right|_{\substack{g(x)=\alpha\\x\in I_k}}=1$$ Summing over $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, we get $$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x &=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{I_k}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\ &=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left.\frac1{\left|g'(x)\right|}\right|_{\substack{g(x)=\alpha\\x\in I_k}}\,f(\alpha)\,\mathrm{d}\alpha\\ &=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(\alpha)\,\mathrm{d}\alpha\end{align}$$

Comment: My last comment was poorly worded.  What I meant was that I didn't know you had placed conditions on $g(x)$ because no conditions are stated in your answer.  That's why I didn't understand $(1)$.

Comment: @RandomVariable: just before equation $(3)$, it says: "Letting $g(x)=x+\tan(x)$, ..."

Comment: I'm referring specifically to equation $(1)$, which is stated without any mention of conditions on $g(x)$.

Comment: Well, $(1)$ is valid for any $g$ as long as the reciprocal of the derivative is integrable.

Comment: It would seem to me that a necessary condition for equation $(1)$ is that the real axis can be divided into intervals where $g(x)$ increases monotonically from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. That's not a necessary condition?

Comment: Not necessarily. Let $g(x)=e^{-x^2}$, then $(1)$ becomes $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f\!\left(e^{-x^2}\right)\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1\frac1{\alpha\sqrt{-\log(\alpha)}}f(\alpha)\,\mathrm{d}\alpha $$

Comment: But the integration limits on the right side of equation $(1)$ are ${-\infty}$ and ${\infty}$.

Comment: Yes, and $\frac1{|g'|}=\frac1{2|x|e^{-x^2}}=\frac1{2\alpha\sqrt{-\log(\alpha)}}$, so why do we have $\frac1{\alpha\sqrt{-\log(\alpha)}}$ in the integral? Read the sum on the righthand side carefully.

Comment: It's because $\alpha = e^{-x^{2}}$ is not invertible on $(-\infty, \infty)$, but $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}} \mathrm dx = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx$. Unfortunately, I don't know how that helps to explain why the interval of integration on the right side of equation $(1)$ is $(-\infty, \infty)$ regardless of what the substitution $\alpha=g(x)$ does to the limits of integration.

Comment: @RandomVariable: The limits of integration are $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ to accommodate a $g$ whose range is $(-\infty,+\infty)$. For a $g$ with a smaller range, the sum on the right will be an empty sum (thus $0$) for values of $\alpha$ outside the range of $g$.

Comment: Now it makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: @TymaGaidash: Where are you getting $a_j$? Note that $h(a)=\sum\limits_{g(x)=a}\frac1{|g'(x)|}$ is a function of $a$. The integral we want is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(a)f(a)\,\mathrm{d}a$.

Comment: @robjohn It is a [bit hard to visualize](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4618585/is-int-infty-infty-sum-gx-a-fracfag-x-da-left-frac1g) how write out $\sum_{g(x)=a}\frac1{|g’(x)|}$, so $g(x)=a\implies x=a_j $ being the $j$th solution. By write out, it means $\sum_n w_n=w_1+\dots +w_i$. Thanks

Comment: @TymaGaidash: There is *one* $a$. There may be a set of $x_j$ so that $g(x_j)=a$, we add up $h(a)=\sum\limits_j\frac1{|g'(x_j)|}$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In that case we factor out $\frac1{|g’(x_j)|}$ from the integral since it is a constant wrt $a$.

Comment: @TymaGaidash: yes, $\sum\limits_{g(x)=\alpha}\frac1{|g'(x)|}=1$ for all $\alpha$. This is what is special about $g(x)=x+\tan(x)$.