# Why does $x+\tan x$ satisfy Glasser's master theorem?

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

[Glasser's Master Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html) States that if a function $\phi(x)$ can be written as $$|a|x-\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{|\alpha_n|}{x-\beta_n}\tag{1}$$for a constant $a$ and sequences $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$ that are defined on the integers between $1$ and $N$, then we have that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\phi(x))dx$$Where the LHS exists and its integrand is integrable. This theorem is used to prove that $$\int_0^\infty \text{sech}^2(x+\tan x)dx=2$$ (given in the MIT integration Bee, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627456/evaluate-int-0-infty-textsech2x-tanxdx)) which means that $x+\tan x$ can be written in the form of $(1)$. But what would $a,\alpha_n,\beta_n$ and $N$ be? I tried using the taylor series expansion of $\tan x$ but its coefficient is a monster, and the sum is infinite.

This is NOT a duplicate to the second link since I am wondering how $x+\tan x$ can be written in the form of $(1)$.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015462/a-strange-integral-int-infty-infty-dx-over-1-leftx-tan-x-rig) has an explanation from user Olivier Oloa

Comment: Pls don't take it otherwise, but dude I'm literally speechless that you're just in 8th grade and you know this much calculus +1

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Thanks for the compliment :) To add to the insanity, I only started to learn advanced math less than a year ago.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thank you for the link, but it doesn’t quite answer my question. I want to know how to re-write $x+\tan x$ in the form of $(1)$

Comment: Here , we have transcendental $\tan$ , hence $N$ has to be infinite. Then $a$ , $\alpha_n$ , $\beta_n$ are not unique.

Comment: In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627456/evaluate-int-0-infty-textsech2x-tanxdx (same link as given by OP), a series is introduced for $\tan x$ as$$\tan x=-\frac{1}{x-\pi/2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{x-\pi n-\pi/2}+\frac{1}{x+\pi n-\pi/2}).$$Why does not this help?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz Assalamu alaikum, the two terms in the sum make a denominator with $x^2$ and not $x$ when combined into a single fraction. Maybe it can be simplified but I am not sure since I am on the phone right now.

Comment: @Prem What do you mean by not unique? I know only so much.

Comment: Are you sure the equation in $(1)$ is correct? It can't be. Assuming you meant $\sum_{n=1}^{N}$, set every $\alpha_n = 0$ and you can see a contradiction.

Comment: Both [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem) and the Mathworld article use a similar formula to that of the OP

Comment: @Accelerator oops, you're right. Thanks

Comment: And if you don't mind me being nitpicky, the theorem says $\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x)dx=\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\phi(x))dx$, which is generally different from $\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\phi(x))dx$. But for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{sech}^2(x+\tan x)dx=2$ it's fine to omit the $\operatorname{PV}$ operator because the integrand has removable discontinuities at $x=(2n+1)\pi/2$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: 'Maybe it can be simplified but I am not sure since I am on the phone right now.' Wow!

Comment: I will elaborate my Previous Comment : [[1]] When $N$ is finite , we will have rational function which can not give the transcendental function $\tan$ , hence $N$ is infinite here. [[2]] When we make $\alpha_n=1$ , we will get certain $\beta_n$ values. When we make $\alpha_n=n$ , we will get alternate $\beta_n$ values. When we make $\alpha_n=n^2$ , we will get variant $\beta_n$ values. In other words , We can control $\alpha_n$ unknowns to generate the $\beta_n$ unknowns , hence there may be no unique way to get those values. [[3]] Exact Solution is unnecessary , Solution Existence is enough !