# Examples of inappropriate credit in mathematics

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, analysis, math-history, big-list

What are some known cases of inappropriate credit in mathematics?

Here, "inappropriate credit" means a common attribution that is not totally fair because someone who also discovered the result is forgotten or because the one who is named did not discover the result. For example:

- From the chronological point of view, the *Argand diagram* should be called *Wessel diagram*.
- From the discovery point of view, the *L'Hospital's rule* should be called *Bernoulli's rule*.

The answer can address any field (this is why I added some specific tags).

Comment: It will have a reason that L'Hospitals' rule has this name. I have also heard of claims that Pythagoras did not discover "$a^2+b^2 =c^2$". Why on earth should it nevertheless be named after him ? Anyway, this question better fits on a math history site (hsm?).

Comment: There are also examples in physics. Einstein did not discover the famous "$E=mc^2$"-equation. It was discovered much earlier.

Comment: Fermat’s Last Theorem?

Comment: @Aphelli Do you mean that he did not actually prove it ? Or that he did not discover it ?

Comment: I just realised this is a dupe: [Theorems' names that don't credit the right people](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410457/theorems-names-that-dont-credit-the-right-people)

Answer (score 1):

An interesting inappropriate credit is for the [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange), not mentioning Ralph Merkle.

Hellman himself suggested the algorithm be called Diffie–Hellman–Merkle key exchange and has quoted that:

*"The system...has since become known as Diffie–Hellman key exchange. While that system was first described in a paper by Diffie and me, it is a public key distribution system, a concept developed by Merkle, and hence should be called 'Diffie–Hellman–Merkle key exchange' if names are to be associated with it. I hope this small pulpit might help in that endeavor to recognize Merkle's equal contribution to the invention of public key cryptography."*

I find it very interesting that one of the names of the key exchange actually would like to add another name for credit.

Answer (score 0):

[Burnside's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma), famously (a) not due to Burnside and (b) not even really a lemma.

(a) is because Burnside himself credits it to Frobenius.  (b) is because it is very useful and non-trivial.

Comment: Really ? Hard to believe !